# Disabling Touchpad while typing [Ubuntu 16.04] [Asus ZenBook]

Tags: unity, launcher

I've been having an issue with disabling the touchpad while typing. I've tried the `syndaemon -i 1 -d` command and it will work, but then, without warning, the touchpad seems to be disabled for movement. (I can still click using the physical touchpad buttons.)

Answer (score 0):

If you manualy started `syndaemon` with custom parameters, you need to disable this option in System Settings -> Mouse, because it also starts `syndaemon` with default parameters.

Starting two instances of `syndaemon` causes cursor freezes, etc.